# RiveScript with Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I want to use RiveScript in a Meteor project. I can't get things running though. I install RiveScript through npm, then followed the guide on the npm site.

The file that reads RiveScript module and gives it a user input.

```
var RiveScript = require("RiveScript");
var bot;

function loadingDone(files) {
    console.log("ok")
}

function loadingError(files, error) {
    console.log("error");
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
    bot = new RiveScript({utf8: true});
    bot.loadDirectory("brain", loadingDone, loadingError);
    bot.sortReplies();
});

Meteor.methods({
    'user-input': function (input) {
        return bot.reply("local-user", input);
    }
});
```

I get this error (on server):

> (STDERR) User local-user was in an empty topic named 'random'

The return message from the bot.reply() function is:

> ERR: No default topic 'random' was found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RiveScript author here.

One problem in your code is that the `sortReplies()` function needs to be called *after* the replies have finished loading (in the `loadingDone` handler).

```js
var RiveScript = require("RiveScript");
var bot;

function loadingDone(files) {
    console.log("ok");
    bot.sortReplies();
}

function loadingError(files, error) {
    console.log("error");
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
    bot = new RiveScript({utf8: true});
    bot.loadDirectory("brain", loadingDone, loadingError);
});

Meteor.methods({
    'user-input': function (input) {
        return bot.reply("local-user", input);
    }
});
```

If you still have trouble after that, try making sure that RiveScript has fully loaded the reply set before Meteor initializes. Looking at your code, it should be fine because the `bot` variable is global and if the `user-input` handler doesn't get called *immediately*, the bot should be ready by the time it is.

Another thing to try is to verify the replies are getting loaded at all; turn on debug mode and see if it prints the contents of the RiveScript files that it's parsing; if not it might mean it's loading from the wrong directory and not finding any `*.rive` files to parse.

Comment: My problem was due to the directory. I couldn't figure out the relative path form the JS file, and now I just use the absolute path.